# Parent animation is affecting main camera rotation(is child)Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have developed a runner game in unity, i have completed the coding part, but when i applied the animation to my character object(which is rotation in z-axis) the camera also rotates with it.
So, how can i stop this rotation of main camera which is child of my main runner object. Also **i don't want any change in rotation of Main Camera**

Main Camera Transform:-

- The Initial Position is(3,13,-28).
- The Initial Rotation is(20,0,0).
- The Initial Scale is (0,0,0).

Some of the code i have tried in a separate script an attached it to main camera:-

1. transform.parent = null;
2. Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
3. Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(20,0f,0f);
4. distanceTraveled1 = new Vector3(runnercode.distanceTraveled,0f,0f);
5. Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (runnercode.distanceTraveled, 0f, 0f);(works,but rotation is always changes)

Any solution? i use C# scripting

Comment: Unity tag has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine on stack overflow. Please don't use it with this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be in `LateUpdate` if you want to be sure it corrects the rotation before the frame is rendered. But have you considered making a separate "FollowObject" script so the camera doesn't need to be a child object? You might find additional uses for it, too. Because you really don't want any of the other semantics of the parent/child relationship besides position.

And I don't think your direction code is right. You are treating distance as an angle. `eulerAngles` refers to degrees x/y/z, not a direction vector. To use a direction vector, you would assign `transform.forward = direction;`. What direction exactly are you trying to look? Toward something? Same (arbitrary) direction every frame? `transform.LookAt()` and `transform.rotation = storedRotation` are easy solutions for those problems.

Edit: Just to be perfectly clear, I think having the camera attached to a character is a bad idea. You will probably encounter problems with jerky movement and incorrect positions at the very least.

Comment: The camera cannot be the runner's parent, either. That will mostly cause the same sort of problems. And you can't set an angle to a distance. It makes no sense. If that number is meant to be part of a direction vector, you can either convert it to an angle, or use `transform.forward =`. But you can't just use the distance unit as an angle, it won't work.

Comment: My runner object is running in x-direction, and i have tried to make the main camera parent and add the transform.forward = direction, but my distance travelled calculates the distance so it is a float value(distanceTraveled = tranform.localPosition.x) and the velocity is a Vector3 so the complier cannot implicitly convert to float.
can you tell how to use the Lateupdate/transform.rotation/transform.lookat to stop rotation of camera.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your rotation setting code in `LateUpdate` on the camera:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(20,0f,0f);
}
```